# Postgres - Wildcard two values query on an array

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a query that will return results only if two values exist in an array field.

I've tried it with 'Like Any' but without any success. 
I tried the following query, but it won't work because unnest creates a separate row for every item of the array.

The last query I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM   SomeTable s
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT
    FROM   unnest(s.tags) tag
    WHERE  tag LIKE '%DataA%' AND tag like '%DataB%'
  );
```

Comment: Maybe you want **OR** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regexp contains operation:

```
select *
  from sometable s
 where tag ~ 'Data(A|B)';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some boolean aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   SomeTable s
WHERE (
    SELECT bool_or(u.tag LIKE '%DataA%') AND bool_or(u.tag LIKE '%DataB%')
    FROM   unnest(s.tags) u (tag)
  );
```